# Media query in css not working

Tags: html, css, media

I am having some issues with implementing my media queries on my index page.

When I resize my page in my browser, I still get the mobile and the desktop version even though they are specified in different media queries.

My mobile version doesn't seem to be getting any styling either :/

Does anybody see my fault here?

```css
@charset "utf-8";

@font-face {
    font-family: sinhala;
    src: url(fonts/Sinhala.ttc);
}

*{
 padding: 0%;
 margin: 0%;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 
}





*//

Index desktop

*//

@media only screen and (min-width: 751px){

#content {
 width:100%;
 position:relative;
 float:left;

}

#wrapper {
 width: 100%;
 position: relative;
 float:left;
}

#background {
 width: 100%;
 position: relative;
 float:left;
 
}

#logo {
 width: 35%;
 position:relative;
 float:left;
 margin-left: 2.5%;
 margin-top: -55% ; 

}

#button {
 width: 20%;
 position:relative;
 float:left;
 margin-top: -27%;
 margin-left: 40%;

}

#buttonhover {
 width: 20%;
 position:relative;
 float:left;
 margin-top: -27%;
 margin-left: 40%;
 display:none;
 
}

#welkom {
 width: 10%;
 position:relative;
 float:left;
 margin-top: -23%;
 margin-left: 44.5%;
}

}
*//

Index mobile

*//

@media only screen and (max-width: 750px) {

body {
 background: none;
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
}

#contentmobile {
 width: 95%;
 height:auto;
 margin-top:2.5%;
 margin-left: 2.5%;
 position:relative;
 float:left;
}

.backgroundmobile {
 width: 100%;
 
 position: relative;
 float:left;
 
}

#background1mobile{
 background-image: url(images/background.png);
 background-size: cover;
 width: 100%;
 height: 715px;
 position:relative;
 float:left;
}

#logomobile {
 width: 55%;
 margin-left: 1.5%;
 margin-top: 1.5%;
 position:relative;
 float:left;
}

#maillogomobile {
 width: 100%;
 position:relative;
 float:left;
}

#maillinkmobile {
 width: 10%;
 float: left;
 position:relative;
 margin-top: 4%;
 margin-left: 30%;
}

#text1mobile {
 width: 55%;
 position:relative;
 float: left;
 margin-left: 22.5%;
 margin-top:42.5%;
}

#trianglemobile {
 width: 20%;
 float:left;
 position:relative;
 margin-top: 103%;
 margin-left: -40%;
}

#klikhiermobile {
 width: 100%;
 float:left;
 position:relative;
}
 

#klikhierlinkmobile {
 width:35%;
 float:left;
 position:relative;
 margin-top: 15%;
 margin-left: 30.5%;
}

#background2mobile {
 width: 100%;
 height: 630px;
 margin-top: 10px;
 background-color: #E6E5E5;

}

#text2mobile {
 width:60%;
 margin-left: 20%;
 position:relative;
 float: left;
 margin-top: 4%;
}

#text3mobile {
 width: 65%;
 margin-left: 17.5%;
 position: relative;
 float: left;
 margin-top: 8%;
}

#ipadlogomobile{
 width: 20%;
 margin-left: 5%;
 position: relative;
 float: left;
 margin-top: 16%;
}

#gsmlogomobile {
 width: 12.25%;
 margin-left: 17.5%;
 position: relative;
 float: left;
 margin-top: 16%;
 }

#desktoplogomobile {
 width: 25%;
 margin-left: 15%;
 position: relative;
 float: left;
 margin-top: 16%;
 }

#text4mobile {
 width: 70%;
 margin-left: 15%;
 position: relative;
 float:left;
 margin-top: 5%;
}

#background3mobile {
 width: 100%;
 height: 900px;
 margin-top:10px;
 background-color: #CC0000;
}

#text5mobile {
 width: 45%;
 margin-left: 27.5%;
 margin-top:8%;
 float:left;
 position:relative;
}

#text6mobile {
 width: 90%;
 margin-left: 5%;
 float:left;
 position:relative;
 margin-top: 12% ;
}

#text7mobile {
 width: 90%;
 margin-left: 5%;
 margin-top: 100%;
 position:relative;
 float:left;
}

#formmobile {
  width: 80%;
  height: 30vw;
  float:left;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 3vw;
  margin-left: 10%;
  display: block;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  font-family: sinhala;
}

#formmobile input  {
 width:100%;
 height: 1vw;
 background-color:#ffffff;
 border:1px solid black;
 padding:5%;
 margin-top:0.5%;
 font-size:4vw;
 color:#3a3a3a;
 border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
 font-family: sinhala;
 background: #ffffff;
}

#formmobile textarea {
 width:100%;
 height:30vw;
 background-color: #ffffff;
 background:#ffffff;
 border:1px solid black;
 padding:5%;
 margin-top:2px;
 font-size:4vw;
 color:#3a3a3a;
 border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
 font-family: sinhala;
 
}

#buttoncontactmobile {
 width: 50%;
 margin-left: 25%;
 margin-top: 5%;
 height: 8vw;
 border:1px solid black;
 font-family: sinhala;
 font-size: 4vw;
 background-color: #ffffff;
 border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
 opacity: 0.7;
 letter-spacing: 2px;
}

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<title> Pieter's Web Design </title>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">
</head>

<body>
<div id="content">

 <div id="wrapper">
  <img id="background" src="images/background.png" />
  <img id="logo" src="images/logo.png" />
  <img id="button" src="images/button.png" />
  <a id="buttonlink" href="homepage.html"><img id="buttonhover" src="images/buttoncopy.png" /></a>
  <a id="welkomlink" href="homepage.html"><img id="welkom" src="images/welkom.png" /> </a>


 </div>
</div>


<div id="contentmobile">


  <div class="backgroundmobile" id="background1mobile">
   <img id="logomobile" src="imagesmobile/logo.png" />
    <a id="maillinkmobile" href="#" onclick=""><img id="maillogomobile" src="imagesmobile/emaillogo.png" /></a>
     <img id="text1mobile" src="imagesmobile/H1.png" />
      <img id="trianglemobile" src="imagesmobile/triangle.png" />
       <a id="klikhierlinkmobile" href="#" onclick=""><img id="klikhiermobile" src="imagesmobile/klikhier.png" /></a>

   <div id="empty_divmobile">
   </div>

  </div>

  <div class="backgroundmobile" id="background2mobile">
   <img id="text2mobile" src="imagesmobile/H2.png" />
   <img id="text3mobile" src="imagesmobile/text3.png" />
   <img id="ipadlogomobile" src="imagesmobile/ipadlogo.png" />
   <img id="gsmlogomobile" src="imagesmobile/gsmlogo.png" />
   <img id="desktoplogomobile" src="imagesmobile/desktoplogo.png" />
   <img id="text4mobile" src="imagesmobile/text4.png" />
  </div>

  <div class="backgroundmobile" id="background3mobile">
  <img id="text5mobile" src="imagesmobile/text5.png" />
  <img id="text6mobile" src="imagesmobile/text6.png" />

  <form id="formmobile" action="php/send.php" method="POST">
        
   <label>Naam</label>
    <input name="Naam" placeholder="Typ hier">
    <br />
    <br />
            
   <label>Email</label>
    <input name="Email" type="Email" placeholder="Typ hier">
    
    <br />
    <br />
    
   <label>Telefoon</label>
    <input name="Telefoon" type="Telefoon" placeholder="Typ hier">
    
    <br />
    <br />
            
   <label>Bericht</label>
    <textarea name="Bericht" placeholder="Typ hier"></textarea>
    
   <button id="buttoncontactmobile" name="Verstuur" value="Verstuur" type="Submit" form="form">Verstuur</button>
   
            </form>

  <img id="text7mobile" src="imagesmobile/text7.png" />

  </div>


</div>



<script src="js/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
<script src="js/hover.js"></script>
<script src="js/scrolldown.js"></script>
</body>

</body>




</html>
```

Comment: Could you simplify it down for us, so we can just focus on the part that's not working for you?

Comment: You mean both is visible?

Comment: yeah sure "@media" only screen and (min-width: 751px){ code for desktop version },  "@media" only screen and (max-width: 750px) { code for mobile version }   yet it does not resize when i resize my browser also should it not automatically hide all the elements which are not the media querie?

Comment: You should put media queries in different files

Comment: Give each content id a `display: none` out side the queries and then set them back inside

Comment: I put the "" around media so i could post it they are not in my code obv ;)

Comment: Ok balint I get what you mean by that but is my media querie on it's own correct the written code "@"media ......

Comment: I'm taking a stab here, but your media queries should always be last since css is parsed top-down. You hit your media queries first, then the css below overrides it.

Comment: My css only exists out of 2 different media queries so don't really get your point here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sample which hides/shows each div based on each media query.

I added these two rules, one in each query

```
#contentmobile {
    display: none;
}

#content {
    display: none;
}
```

Also, the `*//` characters mess up your CSS, use `/* comment */` instead

```css
@charset "utf-8";

@font-face {
    font-family: sinhala;
    src: url(fonts/Sinhala.ttc);
}

*{
 padding: 0%;
 margin: 0%;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 
}





/* Index desktop */


@media only screen and (min-width: 751px){

#contentmobile {
    display: none;
}

#content {
 width:100%;
 position:relative;
 float:left;

}

#wrapper {
 width: 100%;
 position: relative;
 float:left;
}

#background {
 width: 100%;
 position: relative;
 float:left;
 
}

#logo {
 width: 35%;
 position:relative;
 float:left;
 margin-left: 2.5%;
 margin-top: -55% ; 

}

#button {
 width: 20%;
 position:relative;
 float:left;
 margin-top: -27%;
 margin-left: 40%;

}

#buttonhover {
 width: 20%;
 position:relative;
 float:left;
 margin-top: -27%;
 margin-left: 40%;
 display:none;
 
}

#welkom {
 width: 10%;
 position:relative;
 float:left;
 margin-top: -23%;
 margin-left: 44.5%;
}

}
/*

Index mobile

*/

@media only screen and (max-width: 750px) {

#content {
    display: none;
}    

body {
 background: none;
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
}

  
#contentmobile {
 width: 95%;
 height:auto;
 margin-top:2.5%;
 margin-left: 2.5%;
 position:relative;
 float:left;
}

.backgroundmobile {
 width: 100%;
 
 position: relative;
 float:left;
 
}

#background1mobile{
 background-image: url(images/background.png);
 background-size: cover;
 width: 100%;
 height: 715px;
 position:relative;
 float:left;
}

#logomobile {
 width: 55%;
 margin-left: 1.5%;
 margin-top: 1.5%;
 position:relative;
 float:left;
}

#maillogomobile {
 width: 100%;
 position:relative;
 float:left;
}

#maillinkmobile {
 width: 10%;
 float: left;
 position:relative;
 margin-top: 4%;
 margin-left: 30%;
}

#text1mobile {
 width: 55%;
 position:relative;
 float: left;
 margin-left: 22.5%;
 margin-top:42.5%;
}

#trianglemobile {
 width: 20%;
 float:left;
 position:relative;
 margin-top: 103%;
 margin-left: -40%;
}

#klikhiermobile {
 width: 100%;
 float:left;
 position:relative;
}
 

#klikhierlinkmobile {
 width:35%;
 float:left;
 position:relative;
 margin-top: 15%;
 margin-left: 30.5%;
}

#background2mobile {
 width: 100%;
 height: 630px;
 margin-top: 10px;
 background-color: #E6E5E5;

}

#text2mobile {
 width:60%;
 margin-left: 20%;
 position:relative;
 float: left;
 margin-top: 4%;
}

#text3mobile {
 width: 65%;
 margin-left: 17.5%;
 position: relative;
 float: left;
 margin-top: 8%;
}

#ipadlogomobile{
 width: 20%;
 margin-left: 5%;
 position: relative;
 float: left;
 margin-top: 16%;
}

#gsmlogomobile {
 width: 12.25%;
 margin-left: 17.5%;
 position: relative;
 float: left;
 margin-top: 16%;
 }

#desktoplogomobile {
 width: 25%;
 margin-left: 15%;
 position: relative;
 float: left;
 margin-top: 16%;
 }

#text4mobile {
 width: 70%;
 margin-left: 15%;
 position: relative;
 float:left;
 margin-top: 5%;
}

#background3mobile {
 width: 100%;
 height: 900px;
 margin-top:10px;
 background-color: #CC0000;
}

#text5mobile {
 width: 45%;
 margin-left: 27.5%;
 margin-top:8%;
 float:left;
 position:relative;
}

#text6mobile {
 width: 90%;
 margin-left: 5%;
 float:left;
 position:relative;
 margin-top: 12% ;
}

#text7mobile {
 width: 90%;
 margin-left: 5%;
 margin-top: 100%;
 position:relative;
 float:left;
}

#formmobile {
  width: 80%;
  height: 30vw;
  float:left;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 3vw;
  margin-left: 10%;
  display: block;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  font-family: sinhala;
}

#formmobile input  {
 width:100%;
 height: 1vw;
 background-color:#ffffff;
 border:1px solid black;
 padding:5%;
 margin-top:0.5%;
 font-size:4vw;
 color:#3a3a3a;
 border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
 font-family: sinhala;
 background: #ffffff;
}

#formmobile textarea {
 width:100%;
 height:30vw;
 background-color: #ffffff;
 background:#ffffff;
 border:1px solid black;
 padding:5%;
 margin-top:2px;
 font-size:4vw;
 color:#3a3a3a;
 border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
 font-family: sinhala;
 
}

#buttoncontactmobile {
 width: 50%;
 margin-left: 25%;
 margin-top: 5%;
 height: 8vw;
 border:1px solid black;
 font-family: sinhala;
 font-size: 4vw;
 background-color: #ffffff;
 border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
 opacity: 0.7;
 letter-spacing: 2px;
}

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<title> Pieter's Web Design </title>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">
</head>

<body>
<div id="content">

 <div id="wrapper">
  <img id="background" src="images/background.png" />
  <img id="logo" src="images/logo.png" />
  <img id="button" src="images/button.png" />
  <a id="buttonlink" href="homepage.html"><img id="buttonhover" src="images/buttoncopy.png" /></a>
  <a id="welkomlink" href="homepage.html"><img id="welkom" src="images/welkom.png" /> </a>


 </div>
</div>


<div id="contentmobile">


  <div class="backgroundmobile" id="background1mobile">
   <img id="logomobile" src="imagesmobile/logo.png" />
    <a id="maillinkmobile" href="#" onclick=""><img id="maillogomobile" src="imagesmobile/emaillogo.png" /></a>
     <img id="text1mobile" src="imagesmobile/H1.png" />
      <img id="trianglemobile" src="imagesmobile/triangle.png" />
       <a id="klikhierlinkmobile" href="#" onclick=""><img id="klikhiermobile" src="imagesmobile/klikhier.png" /></a>

   <div id="empty_divmobile">
   </div>

  </div>

  <div class="backgroundmobile" id="background2mobile">
   <img id="text2mobile" src="imagesmobile/H2.png" />
   <img id="text3mobile" src="imagesmobile/text3.png" />
   <img id="ipadlogomobile" src="imagesmobile/ipadlogo.png" />
   <img id="gsmlogomobile" src="imagesmobile/gsmlogo.png" />
   <img id="desktoplogomobile" src="imagesmobile/desktoplogo.png" />
   <img id="text4mobile" src="imagesmobile/text4.png" />
  </div>

  <div class="backgroundmobile" id="background3mobile">
  <img id="text5mobile" src="imagesmobile/text5.png" />
  <img id="text6mobile" src="imagesmobile/text6.png" />

  <form id="formmobile" action="php/send.php" method="POST">
        
   <label>Naam</label>
    <input name="Naam" placeholder="Typ hier">
    <br />
    <br />
            
   <label>Email</label>
    <input name="Email" type="Email" placeholder="Typ hier">
    
    <br />
    <br />
    
   <label>Telefoon</label>
    <input name="Telefoon" type="Telefoon" placeholder="Typ hier">
    
    <br />
    <br />
            
   <label>Bericht</label>
    <textarea name="Bericht" placeholder="Typ hier"></textarea>
    
   <button id="buttoncontactmobile" name="Verstuur" value="Verstuur" type="Submit" form="form">Verstuur</button>
   
            </form>

  <img id="text7mobile" src="imagesmobile/text7.png" />

  </div>


</div>



<script src="js/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
<script src="js/hover.js"></script>
<script src="js/scrolldown.js"></script>
</body>

</body>




</html>
```

Comment: changed what you said no succes unfortunately, must be something else it beats me though.  I do think what you said would also have been necesarry to block out the unwanted elements in for the different queries so thx for that already :)

Comment: @Pieter Are you saying my posted code snippet above doesn't work when it comes to the media query's? .. If you resize the above it does, so if not, how does it not work for you?

Comment: Well i used the same code but it did not resize. Gave it another go through html this using <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css" media="only screen and (min-width: 421px)" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="indexmobile.css" media="only screen and (max-width: 420px)" /> This time around the mobile version is resizing however when i have a screen larger then 421 px is still shows all the mobile content despite having #contentmobile { display: none} in the css

Comment: @Pieter In that case it is something wrong with your meta viewport tag, not the update I suggested.

Comment: I am using <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/> seems correct no?

Comment: @Pieter Great. If my answer helped you with the major fix, please accept it, if not, post a self answer.

Comment: @Pieter You click on the gray "check mark" at the top left of the answer of your choice